# With a custom navigation controller push transition, how do I have the previous view controller behind like modal presentations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

When performing a custom **modal** view controller transition, the view controller you're coming from sits behind the new one nicely (think of Apple's "form sheet" style presentation on an iPad for instance), and when you rotate the device the previous view controller visible in the back rotates as well.

I'm unsure how to get this functionality with a `UINavigationController` custom push animation. It seems it isn't expected for the previous view controller to be visible from behind and it isn't.

I could take a screenshot, but it won't update on landscape rotation.

How is it done so easily with a modal transition and how do I replicate that for navigation controller custom transitions?

Comment: Two very different things... Modal view: show a view *on top of* another view. Push navigation: *push* a new view in while pushing the current view out. So, short answer is - you *don't* replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the `UINavigationController` class such functionality cannot be achieved through it.

`UINavigationController` is a container controller, which can show only one VC within it at a time. It keeps all the VCs in the stack, but not their views (views are kept by VCs themselves).

Unlike it, the modal presentation is a special type of VC-presentation, and it's not limited by the container-functionality.